# how to create jQuery plugin with options but no element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a plugin that does not need a DOM element but does have default options.

When I run the code below I get `TypeError: $.myApp is not a function`.

What do I need to change?

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    var defaults = {
        val: 'old value'
    };

    function myApp (options) {      
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this.init();
    };

    $.extend(myApp .prototype, {
        init: function () {
            console.log (this.settings);
        }
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);

$(function() {
    $.myApp({
        val: 'new value'
    });
});
```

Comment: You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/k7h90y9h/

Comment: Sorry, correct link is http://jsfiddle.net/k7h90y9h/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k7h90y9h/2/)

```
(function ($) {
         $.myApp = function(options){
             var defaults = {
                 'default'          : ''
             };
             var options = jQuery.extend(defaults,options);

            alert('worked!')
         }
     })($);

$(function() {

    $.myApp({
        val: 'new value'
    });


});
```

The answer is not like your function but it works on the right way.

Comment: what about the `init` function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is full tutorial that can help you.

We will start with simple plugin. First of all, we need to create js file for plugin. Create a blank file and save it as `jquery.myFirstPlugin.js`. Include it to out html file in end of html file and off course include `jquery-1.11.min.js` as its JQuery plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.myFirstPlugin.js"></script>
```

**Default structure**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myFirstPlugin = function() {
        // your code here
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Here, Include everything in `(function($){})` self-enclosed pattern as we don’t want any confliction with other Javascript snippet on the page. `$.fn` allows you to define function as we gave `myFirstPlugin` name to our plugin. We will do magic inside function.

**Setting default value**
What if no text passed in initialization? Obviously we need to set default settings in our plugin.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myFirstPlugin = function( options ) {

        // Default params
        var params = $.extend({
            text     : 'Default Title',
            fontsize : 10,
        }, options);
        return $(this).text(params.text);

    }
}(jQuery));
```

Here, we have added default object called `params` and set default values of options using `extend` function. Hence, If we pass blank argument then it will set default values instead otherwise it will set.

```
$('.cls-title').myFirstPlugin({ text : 'Argument Title' });
```

**Original Source**

[How to Create JQuery plugin](http://sgeek.org/create-jquery-plugin/)